# Mediawiki and Wikidata

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

What does it mean:
"On a page that is connected to a Wikidata item via the interwiki links, you can use the function by adding the label of the property you want in your language or the P-number of the property. The code has to be added in the wikicode.

{{#statements:member of political party}} or {{#statements:P102}} will return the "member of political party" value.

"?

As far as I understood interwiki links are simply a special kind of link, they don't act on page level and they don't modify the behaviour of the page.

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:How_to_use_data_on_Wikimedia_projects#Direct_access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Wikipedia article can be connected to a Wikidata item. Interwiki links these days are mostly automatically generated between articles in different languages connected to the same Wikidata item. `{{#statements}}` and similar functions pull information from the connected Wikidata item.

Non-Wikimedia wikis do not have similar features currently; Wikidata integration requires direct database access.

Comment: Will this feature be possible for non-wikimedia wikis?

Comment: The [UnlinkedWikibase](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UnlinkedWikibase) extension offers some limited support.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr. I wasn't clear. I meant, will it be possible for non-Wikimedia wiki pages to have non-Wikimedia wikibase items, similar to the Wikipedia/Wikidata integration described by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikidata#Access_from_Wikipedia.

Comment: Sure, you can set up your own Wikibase site, it's all opensource.

Comment: I did, and it doesn't integrate with wikibase as that page describes. There's no menu link to the wikidata item that corresponds to the page, and wikidata items aren't created for every page.

Comment: It's not the most straightforward to set up... but that should probably be asked in a separate question.